# Sublime Text detect overwrite mode

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I am trying to write a plugin to support a vim-like replace mode in [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/).
To accomplish this, there are a couple things that I need to be able to do:

1. enable/disable overwrite mode. (not `toggle_overwrite`).
2. detect if overwrite mode is enabled.

Item 2 is more important because I could always detect and toggle if necessary.

How can I detect if overwrite mode is enabled?

Comment: Does not answer your question but the vintage package already tries to emulate some of vim's functions. You maybe want to submit a pull request to this repo? http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html

Comment: @ElDeveloper, if I can find the feature to check if overwrite mode is enabled, I could write this up with 10 lines of various code. I'd like to find out if thats possible before submitting a request :)

Comment: I was able to use toggle and my own setting to track it get what I wanted. It seems to be working ok so far. functional but less than ideal.

Comment: As long as there's no API support, how about this horrible hack? Check for overwrite mode by adding a character and checking the buffer size before and after. (And undo the insertion afterwards, of course; arrange for the insert to be outside `View.visible_region()`)

Comment: My way is slightly less horrible than that =p. It seems to be working ok so far.

Comment: Remember that you can always answer your own questions so other persons in the future can be enriched by your knowledge.

Comment: @ElDeveloper, I still don't have an answer to the question. My way just works around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the question is tagged "sublimetext2", I'll note that Sublime Text 3 does offer functions to do what you want:

```
view.set_overwrite_status(True) # Or False
view.overwrite_status()
```

Comment: Thanks. I had not realized there was a sublime text 2. I gave up on it since it doesn't implemented nearly enough of the vim features I use. I might have to check it out. Not quite sure if I should accept this answer or not.

Answer (score -5):

This kind of keyboard access requires ncurses or Xwindow access to application. You should add keyboard functions from ncurses.

Comment: This isn't exclusively a Linux application.

Comment: Sublime is actually a GUI editor, not a terminal application.